# Modular Numbers: Not Accounting for Decimal Portion in Decimal Expansion

Tags: terminology, decimal-expansion

Let n = 10, s = 4.

[s] = {s' $\in \mathbb{z}$ | s' $\sim$ s}
= {s' $\in \mathbb{z}$ | 10 | s' - 4}
= {10k+4 | k $\in \mathbb{z}$ }
= {s' $\in \mathbb{z}$ | decimal expansion of s' ends in a 4 if s' is pos, ends in a 6 if s' is
neg}

How does this last line make sense? We know that 4 $\sim$ 14. But, from my understanding of decimal expansions, isn't the decimal expansion of 4 4.0000 (repeating) and 3.9999 (repeating). So how can we say that decimal expansion of 4 ends in a 4? Similarly, we know that -6 $\sim$ -16. But shouldn't the decimal expansion of -6 be -6.0000 (repeating) or -5.99999 (repeating)? So how can we say that decimal expansion of -6 ends in a 6?

It seems like my professor is stopping at the ones digit and not accounting for the "decimal" portion. I think the problem is that I lack a clear understanding of what a "decimal expansion" is.

Edit: Is my teacher just considering one decimal representation out of two?

Comment: They just mean the last digit of the integer in ordinary base 10.  Base 10 is the decimal system.

Comment: @Randall But why say "decimal expansion"? Isn't the decimal expansion of 4 4.0000 or 3.9999 (repeating)? So isn't that just confusing?

Comment: Maybe. Ask your professor for clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question here - but if it helps: your professor might be thinking about decimal expansions **of integers** only - so not even considering anything involving a decimal point. (Or, otherwise said: not ever considering an expansion ending as $.99999\ldots$)

Comment: @MiloBrandt Hi, so what is the decimal expansion of an integer? I thought the decimal expansion of an integer such as 4 always has two representations because integers terminate (4.0000 and 3.9999). Like, what's the point of the decimal expansion of an integer if you don't include the decimal portion in a *decimal* expansion? Forgive me if I'm grossly missing something.

Comment: You are reading too much into the term “decimal.”  It does not mean stuff to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: You do know that integers can be expressed in other bases, right?  Like base 2 is binary?   Your professor just wants you to think in ordinary base 10 (the decimal system).

Comment: @Randall What does "decimal" mean then? I always thought it was the stuff to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: It means base 10.  As opposed to say, binary.

Comment: @Randall Oh. I see. So why would someone say the decimal expansion of 4 is 4.000 or 4.999. Can't it just be plain old 4?

Comment: That is my point.  You SHOULD be taking it as a plain old 4 in this context.

Comment: @Randall Okay, thank you very much. That makes sense.

Comment: Note that the given description of the congruence classes would not make any sense in binary, but it makes perfect sense in base 10.  That’s your professor’s point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "decimal expansion" here is just the way you would write an integer as $267456$ or $127$ or any other string of digits - where there are no decimal points at all to worry about. It's the ordinary way of writing an integer.

Formally, the idea is that the notation $83521$ is really just shorthand for:
$$8\cdot 10^4 +3\cdot 10^3 + 5\cdot 10^2 + 2\cdot 10 + 1$$
where we have a sum over powers of $10$ times digits from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Every non-negative integer can be uniquely expressed in this form (and every negative integer is just the negation of some positive integer) - and, when you're talking only about integers, this is what is meant by "decimal expansion."

There's a generalization of this that applies to all real numbers, where something like
$$13.1415\ldots = 1\cdot 10^1 + 3 + 1\cdot 10^{-1} + 4\cdot 10^{-2}+1\cdot 10^{-3}+5\cdot 10^{-4}+\ldots$$
where we allow negative exponents of $10$ as well (indicated by the decimal point) and also allow infinitely many terms with these negative exponents if we desire. Some numbers can be represented in multiple ways in this notation since $0.999\ldots = 1.000\ldots$. If people are talking about real numbers, this is what "decimal expansion" would mean - but it's not what your professor is referring to.

(Note: The word "decimal" here refers to the fact that we write a number as a sum of powers of ten - which is probably what you were going to do anyways. Other bases can be indicated in the same terminology - for instance, the term "ternary expansion" refers to writing a number as a sum of powers of $3$ times values in $\{0,1,2\}$ and generalizes in the same ways)

Comment: Thank you VERY much for that lucid explanation.